# Knitr::kable not printing to Word in all cases (results='asis' IS set)

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr

Unfortunately I'm running into some kable trouble when knitting to Word.

In an RScript I've created a function which reads a .csv file, merges this data frame with another existing data frame, calculates a ratio between two of the columns, subsets the merged data frame based on Sample Number and finally merges it with a third data frame containing the true value for that group of samples.

At the end of the function I am using: `kable(finalDF)`.

In an Rmd document, I then apply the function and fill in the variables. The function works and gives the desired result when I run it from within the Rmd document. However, when I knit the document, my table doesn't appear (nothing appears). If I use `print(kable(finalDF))` this of course just prints all the text but does not retain the table format. (I also am not running this in a for loop so print shouldn't be necessary).

In my Rmd chunk I DO have `{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'` which I know is necessary.

Checking the `typeof` data frame says it is a `list`. 
Checking the `class` indicates it is a data.frame.

Why I am utterly bewildered is I have another function elsewhere which is the same `typeof` and `class` and has the same commands for the chunk and knitr::kable works just fine for it! I see the table output to word perfectly.

Any thoughts or suggestions with what could be up would be appreciated. Eg. I couldn't find anything that said you couldn't subset and then use kable or that merging two data frames and trying to output using kable caused problems down the line etc.

Relevant chunk appears as:

`{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis', comment=NA}
HPC<-controlFind("20160114 Mix.csv", "20160114 Mix Controls.csv", "CBHP", 500, "Mix3", 5, "HPC")`

Comment: please show the essential parts of the rmd file you have. did you model it after the example you get when you create a new rmarkdown file and choose word document?

Comment: I've added the chunk from the Rmd document to the question. I've also strangely found that I can take out the knitr::kable function from within the function, make a new function in a _different_ Rscript file using `makeTable<-function(df) { knitr::kable(df)}` and if I set that Rscript as a source file for the Rmd to look to it will print the table! I just don't understand why I can't do it all in the same function in the same document...! (though you could say I've found a workaround)